# Aliasing rule applicable to char strings

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

I don't understand why this code triggers off aliasing warning:

```
char buf[15];

*(uint16_t*) buf = 0x4040;
```

There is no any thinkable "alignments" within char type. And anyway, how do I do this in graceful way? So far I can't think of anything better than

```
char buf[15];
uint16_t foo = 0x4040;
memcpy(buf, &foo, 2);
```

The warning is this:

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing) - don't mix them up

Comment: Please add the actual warning(s).

Comment: @self.Thanks, you are right - it's my DSP past kicks in :-)

Comment: You already accepted an answer, otherwise I would post mine, but the gist is that you can declared a `char` array, and you can only cast that to a compatible type which in this case is only a `char`. So the cast is illegal according to standard. If you declared a `uint16_t` array then you could cast that to `uint16_t`  or `char`.

Comment: Actually the warning that you get is a wrong one, hopefully this is not a very new compiler version. Aliasing is allowed with any character types, so the compiler shouldn't complain about these. As nos answer shows correctly there is a problem with alignment, so the compiler should have talked about this.

Comment: @JensGustedt *Aliasing is allowed with any character types, so the compiler shouldn't complain about these.* Not true. You can alias to a compatible type or a char. char's only compatible type is char. If you start with char you can't just cast to anything else. You can however start with a type, cast to char, and then back to type. In this case the effective type of the casted object is char. If you take a look at standard 6.5(7) you can read about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no any thinkable "alignments" within char type.

And that's the problem, a char array normally have the smallest possible alignment requirement, of 1.

However your code tries to treat it as an uint16_t, which might have a different alignment requirement than 1 (typically 2).

The solution you have here is reasonable:

```
char buf[15];
uint16_t foo = 0x1234; //changed this to demonstrate endian issue
memcpy(buf, &foo, 2);
```

The caveat is with both these approaches is the content of `buf` will depend on the endian of your host, i.e. on
a little endian system you will end up with

```
buf[0] == 0x34;
buf[1] == 0x12;
```

While on a big endian system the values will be reversed. If this is of no concern, then all is well.
If it is a concern, instead of the memcpy() you could do:

```
 buf[0] = foo & 0xff;
 buf[1] = foo >> 8;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I though you talked about the casting example.

Comment: @self Well, it will depend on the host endian in both cases.

Comment: As long as OP doesn't send the data he is fine, please edit or I can't undownvote.

Comment: @nos: I see - so some systems may not go easy about alignment of uint32_t itself - I forgot about it. And yes endian issue is all accounted for, in fact it wasn't 0x4040, it was htons()

Comment: *You last voted on this answer 8 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.* <-- this